# LaTeX nomenclature using numbers for sections

Tags: nomenclature

I want to use the nomenclature to make a custom index of files in a directory.
As long as my section starts with a letter, there is no problem. But if I want to section it with a number it does not work.

I got this MWE from [Nomenclature section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223521/nomenclature-section) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{A}]}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{\item[\textbf{0}]}
        {}
    }
    }
}
\makenomenclature
  \nomenclature[A]{$\Omega_N$}{Set of all buses (nodes).}
  \nomenclature[A]{$n,m$}{Index of all buses (nodes). $m$ is alias of $n$.}
  \nomenclature[A]{$\Omega_L$}{Set of all Transmission lines.}
  \nomenclature[A]{$l$}{Index of transmission lines.}
  \nomenclature[0]{$\Omega_{K}$}{Set of all genetors.}
\begin{document}
  Some text
  \printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

What should happen: I get an index with two sections: One starting at 0 (one entry) and the other section A has four entries.

This is what I get: I get an index with a section with no label, one entry and the other section A with four entries. For some reason, 0 is not recognized.

I've tried

```
\ifthenelse{#1=0}}{\item[\textbf{0}]}
```

as well ... no luck. *Maybe 0 is a number and does not like to be compared as string...?!*

**EDIT:**
I need sections 0-9 and a-z for my index.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Substitute the 0 (zero) with a B when checking for equality?

Comment: Well, that might work if I don't use the whole alphabet. Unfortunately I need 0-9, a-z for my index. 
It could/would help, if I could use two letters for sections instead of only one letter.

Comment: I'm afraid `nomencl` is not able to distinguish between digits: when you have `\nomenclature[<digit>]{...}{...}` the entry is placed in the “Symbols” group irrespective of the `<digit>`. And just the first character is used for this purpose.

Comment: @gilu This is a limitation of MakeIndex

Comment: @gilu You may want to look at the `glossaries` package that has much more features.

Comment: @egreg As far as I know `glossaries` can handle only `A...Z` as well as `nomencl` and I think it is for the same reason.

Comment: @karlkoeller It should make easier using Xindy, which might be better in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no answer for the `nomencl` package, here's how you can implement it with the `glossaries` package. This doesn't use `makeindex`'s grouping system, but instead utilizes the hierarchical structure provided by `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
 nopostdot,% suppress automatic post-description full stop
 automake,% automatically run makeindex if restricted shell escape enabled
 nonumberlist,% suppress location lists
 nogroupskip,% suppress group skips (we're overriding the default grouping)
 style=tree% hierarchical display style required
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% \newentry{letter/number}{label}{settings}
\newcommand*{\newentry}[3]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}{}%
  {%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={\nopostdesc}}%
  }%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{parent={#1},sort={#2},#3}%
}

\newentry{A}{omegaN}
 {name={$\Omega_N$},description={Set of all buses (nodes).}}

\newentry{A}{nm}
 {name={$n,m$},description={Index of all buses (nodes). $m$ is alias of $n$.}}

\newentry{A}{omegaL}
 {name={$\Omega_L$},description={Set of all Transmission lines.}}

\newentry{A}{l}
 {name={$l$},description={Index of transmission lines.}}

\newentry{0}{omegaK}
 {name={$\Omega_{K}$},description={Set of all genetors.}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\glsaddall% index all defined entries

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This defines the command `\newentry` which will define the parent entry (for the group) if it hasn't already been defined. It will then define the actual entry as a child entry. Since all the `name` fields use commands or special characters (like `\Omega` or `$`), the `sort` key is set to the label by default to assist `makeindex`'s sorting. This can be changed, if required, in the third argument of `\newentry`.

The result looks like:

[image: image of glossary]

The style can be changed if required. There are a number of predefined styles. You'll need one that can support hierarchical entries. [Table 15.1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:styles) in the user guide provides a summary. You'll need one where the maximum level is greater than 0 but doesn't have the "Homograph" column checked.